# 301 Redirect Single File Update URL

Tags: redirect, asp-classic, http-status-code-301

How can I update the Location Header to redirect to another URL?

Page code:

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<%
    Response.Status="301 Moved Permanently"
    Response.AddHeader "Location","http://www.example.com/new-url.asp"
%>
```

Now I access the page in the browser and get redirected to `www.example.com/new-url.asp`.

I need to change the URL now to `www.example.com/new-url-updated.asp`.

New Page code:

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<%
    Response.Status="301 Moved Permanently"
    Response.AddHeader "Location","http://www.example.com/new-url-updated.asp"
%>
```

Now I access the page and it still redirects me to `www.example.com/new-url.asp` and not `www.example.com/new-url-updated.asp`.

Website is running on IIS, Windows Server 2003.

Comment: The browser is caching the `HTTP 301 Moved Permanently` force the cache to be cleared first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prevent the page to be cached (cf. [Response.CacheControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524721(v=vs.90).aspx)):

```
Response.CacheControl = "no-cache"

Response.Status="301 Moved Permanently"
Response.AddHeader "Location","http://www.example.com/new-url-updated.asp"
```